# Cannot resolve hostname for a specific device

Tags: networking

I setup a raspberry pi with a node-red application running on it.
Using raspi-config, I setup a custom hostname, e.g. *myraspberry*.

From my laptop I can access the node-red dashboard with the hostname instead of the ip:

http://myraspberry:1880/

It works!

But from another laptop I have (in the same networks), it doesn't work. It cannot resolve the hostname (server IP address could not be found ). Both computers are Windows.

How can I fix that?

Why it works on one laptop and not work in another one?

Comment: add an entry to the hosts file on the windows machine https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/.

Comment: What version of Windows runs on each of the PC's?

Comment: This is a problem with Windows or your network. Nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: Run a [search for Bonjour on Windows](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=bonjour+on+windows&atb=v278-1&ia=web)